# Today Extension Widget Using stopwatch Functionality

Tags: ios8-extension

**How to update the value dynamically of the today extension widget.I am using stopwatch in the  containing application.
The value is refreshed when i swipe the screen left and right of widget or on  up and down the screen.
I want is change dynamically while the stopwatch is running in background app
**

Comment: I don't think I understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I want the value from the containing app to today extension while the containing application is minimised and while I tap on today extension it show the containing app main screen.                         for Example- I am displaying the value of the containing app on label which is on today extension screen.

Comment: Any answer on this? I want to dynamically update the today extension as well. i.e., want to keep it update every second...